# Place name to Coordinates Quickest Way

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So I have a list of 241 Colleges and Universities Names that I need to change into longitude and latitude coordinates for a Xcode program that I am working on. What would be the quickest way to do it, the only way I can think of is going to google maps and searching each one.

Thanks in advance.

Arian

Comment: You can do it programmatically using CLLocationCoordinate2D and MapKit Framework... Or involve 4 friends + you, 5 guys, about 50 Colleges each, about 20 seconds spend per College to search = you are done in 15 minutes, spending 4 beers ))) Good luck!

Comment: haha too bad it is summer and all my Fraternity Bros are at home... but i found a great gem of a website http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... this website http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/